# Laravel 5.2 : Object of class Carbon\Carbon could not be converted to int error

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to create array in Laravel 5.2 like this:

```
$newArray = array('il' => $result['il'],
                                'ckys' => intval($result['ckys_kurum_kodu']),
                                'kurum' => $result['kurum'],
                                'aile_hekimligi' => intval($result['aile_hekimligi']),
                                'anesteziyoloji' => intval($result['anesteziyoloji']),
                                'beyin_sinir_cer' => intval($result['beyin_sinir_cer']),
                                'biyokimya' => intval($result['biyokimya']),
                                'cocuk_cer' => intval($result['cocuk_cer']),
                                'cocuk_hast' => intval($result['cocuk_hast']));
```

But I am getting this error:

```
Object of class Carbon\Carbon could not be converted to int
```

What is this error means and how can we handle the solution ?

Thanks

Comment: Carbon is used for dates in Laravel. One of the values you're passing to `intval()` is a date. Find it and fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't convert date to an integer (only to Unix timestamp). But you can convert it to a string. For example, if `cocuk_cer` is a date, you can do this:

```
'cocuk_cer' => $result['cocuk_cer']->toDateTimeString(),
```

Do the same for all dates in an array.

Comment: Infact there is no any dates.But I am getting this error

Comment: Please update your post with what `dd($result);` generates